# PHP Generics with Intellij

Tags: php, generics, intellij-idea

How to use PHP Generics together with Intellij?

```
class Person<T> {

    public function __construct(T $key){

    }

}
```

Intellij marks `Person<T>` as error, because of `<T>`.

**I'm using:**

- PHP Version 7.0.1
- Intellij 14.1.5

**Referring to this site:** https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics

Comment: Generics is not supported yet, not even fully planned in PHP 7.1, so it is not just a parser error...

Answer (score 1):

It is now supported in PHPStorm since version 2018.3.

> PHPDoc PSR-5  collection type hints
>   The PSR-5 PHPDoc standard is in the draft state for some time, and is having an Entrance Vote in the PHP-FIG right now. Meanwhile, in PhpStorm we are already adding Generics-style notation support for collections on parser level. See the Collections section in the standard for more examples.

Source: [PhpStorm blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/09/phpstorm-2018-3-eap-183-2635-12/)

But some caveats:

- PhpStorm recognizes the syntax (it won't throw an error on you) however it will not validate or autocomplete for `<T>`
- PHP itself does not do anything with this yet (current version at the time of writing this answer is 7.4) and has not held a vote on it, so we don't really know when it will come.

Related link: [PHP generics RFC](https://github.com/PHPGenerics/php-generics-rfc).

Answer (score -1):

PHP Generic comes with PHP-Version 7.1

Comment: It did not happen, unfortunately. The RFC still hasn't been even voted on.